# Substract first value of the range to show 0 based counter

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

In grafana, with data source prometheus, I want to show the evolution of a counter starting from 0 to see the number of [x] (for example written_bytes) increase during the shown range, I want to see how it increases over time, so survive system restarts and no showing the rate().

For example, if I select 2 hours in the graph, I want to see how the bytes were written incrementally were the first value is 0 and the last is the total written during those 2 hours.

In pseudo code I want this:

```
written_bytes - (value in written_bytes of the shown range at position 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to do with PromQL, but is possible with [MetricsQL](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/wiki/MetricsQL). For instance, the following query would return increasing graph starting from 0 for `node_network_receive_bytes_total` metric:

```
with (q = remove_resets(node_network_receive_bytes_total)) q - range_first(q)
```

The query uses the following MetricsQL features:

- [With templates](https://victoriametrics.com/promql/expand-with-exprs) aka common table expressions (CTE)
- `remove_resets` function for removing counter resets
- `range_first` function for returning the first value on the selected time range

Answer (score 0):

If you have the variable written_bytes, which is only increasing over time, you could solve it like this.

```
written_bytes - min_over_time(written_bytes[$__range])
```

With $__range you get the time range selected on the upper right in Grafana.

Comment: This query will behave in a not desired way, if a reset is present somewhere within those two hours.

Comment: Ok thanks for the comment, that is of course true, I was considering an only increasing value without resets. But of course some need both.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Klaus did not produce the desired result for me - and I think that is, because all ranges given are sliding ranges using an offset-time of the single data point shown. So [$__range] does have the length of the total view, but is not the range from start() to end().

What I found instead, was indeed that you can use metric@start(), which produces an instant query[1] at the time of start():

```
written_bytes - written_bytes@start()
```

[1] see https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/ - "@ modifier"